# Compiling cURL 7.69.1 with OpenSSL version 1.1.1g

Tags: ssl, centos7, openssl, curl

I am compiling cURL (version 7.69.1) with OpenSSL (version 1.1.1g) on CentOS 7.

This is what i have done --

1. For compiling curl

```
    ./configure --with-ssl --with-nghttp2  {nghttp2 for adding HTTP/2 feature)
    make
    make install
```

2. For compiling OpenSSL

```
    ./config 
     make 
     make test
     make install
```

(Although, i think i should have compiled OpenSSL before cURL but after cURL compilation only, i realized that my current OpeSSL version doesn't supports TLS1.3, so i have to compile the latest version of cURL.)

Now, on trying to access the site over tls1.3, i am getting the following error --

```
#curl https://tls1.3.nkn.in --tlsv1.3 -v
*   Trying 10.40.122.23:443...
* Connected to tls1.3.nkn.in (10.40.122.23) port 443 (#0)
* OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support
* Closing connection 0
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support
```

Then, i tried to compile the cURL again but noticed the following statement in cURL configuration --

```
checking for OpenSSL headers version... 1.1.1 - 0x1010107fL
checking for OpenSSL library version... 1.0.2
```

What should i do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

After hours of troubleshooting, it works by the following steps -

1. Re-compile OpenSSL again with with --prefix option

```
# ./config --prefix=/usr/local/OpenSSL
make
make install
```

2. Re-compile cURL again

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/OpenSSL --with-nghttp2=/usr/local    {nghttp2 for HTTP/2 support}
make
make install
```

The following Output shows compilation of cURL with OpenSSL/1.1.1g AND HTTP/2 support

```
# curl -V
curl 7.69.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.7 nghttp2/1.41.0-DEV
Release-Date: 2020-03-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Thanks.